# How to use chessboard package?

Tags: chessboard

I'm using TexLive under Windows 8 & TexMaker, when I tried to run this code snippet,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chessboard}
\storechessboardstyle{4x4}{maxfield=d4}
\begin{document}
\chessboard[style=4x4,setwhite={Qa1,Qd2},showmover=false]
\end{document}
```

It didn't produce any result, instead a warning said `\usepgfmodule{shapes}` is obsolete. Any idea?

```
This package is obsolete. Use \usepgfmodule{shapes} instead
```

Is there any package for chessboard available in TikZ?

Comment: My compilation produces output. However, this should be submitted as a bug report to Ulrike (IMO).

Comment: @Werner: Thanks. So is there any alternative for drawing chessboard that I'm not aware of?

Comment: In the style you're after (different from 8x8), there's not much. See [Game packages on CTAN](http://ctan.org/topic/games). Ulrike is around here... somewhere...

Comment: @Chan: The example works fine for me on a current miktex 2.9. Also the warning is (currently) harmless.  Add `\listfiles` at the start of your example. Then compile with pdflatex and put the log-file somewhere for inspection.

Comment: Addition: I now tried on a current texlive 2012 too, and it works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alternatively, you can use `skak` package. Here is a sample:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{skak}

\begin{document}
\section*{Chess}

\newgame
\mainline{1.e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3.Bb5}
\[ \showboard \]
\mainline{3...a6} Rarely used these days,
\variation{3...Nf6} is more in fashion since blah blah... \\
\mainline{4.Ba4}
\[ \showboard \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So how about a 4x4 style chessboard?

Comment: @Werner, well, my bad. I didn't notice the 4x4 part in the code of the question and I'm not sure if `skak` or `xskak` support that. Should I remove the answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the "diagram" package:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{diagram}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{diagram}[4x4] 
\pieces{wDa1, wDd2} 
\end{diagram}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I can't find a "diagram" package in CTAN. It is an official package?